# CSS @media queries for high-res displays not working

Tags: css, media, media-queries, retina-display

I've set up a bit of CSS to detect whether the client's using a Retina or other HiDPI display, and display a different `background-image` for various `div`s based on that. Here's my syntax:

```
<!-- LoDPI and MedDPI displays -->
#div {
    opacity:0.4;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:2;
    width:1600px;
    height:900px;
    animation-name:ring;
    animation-delay:0s;
    animation-duration:1500ms;
    animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.225, 1.650, 0.000, 0.805);
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    background-image:url(/valid/path/to/regular/file);
}

<!-- For Retina and HiDPI displays -->
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4) {
#div {
    background-image:url(/valid/link/to/HiDPI/file);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:contain;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try this out on my Retina MBP, whose pixel ratio is set to 1.5 ("acts like 1920x1200), displays the normal-res images rather than the high-res ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have all your curly braces closed. Regardless, for better support matrix, substitute your media query with

```
@media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
         /*your rules*/
       }
```

Comment: Actually, I should mention that I've got the Prefix Free JS included, and that I missed the closing `@media` bracket in my initial question.

Comment: I couldn't be sure if it were a typo or not. Are you using CSS comments instead of HTML ones as well? I'm not familiar with how well different *Prefix Free*-like JS workarounds work with media queries though.

Comment: So far, they work quite well; all other media queries on my site work fine (most are for resolutions), and use the same syntax.

Comment: Actually, do you know if the W3C spec includes a `max-device-pixel-ratio` in addition to the `min-device-pixel-ratio`?

Comment: That's min--moz-device-pixel-ratio. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:
min-device-pixel-ratio seems not to be supported (prefixed) by prefix-free js!? 
min-device-pixel-ratio isn't W3C compliant.

When I use it with vendor prefixes, everything works fine?!

this works fine for me (delete the comments)

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), /*  Firefox16, Chrome, Safari, iOS, Android */
       (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),    /*  Older Firefox browsers (prior to Firefox16) */
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),    /*  Opera */
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),         /*  not defined yet, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ */
       (min-resolution: 2dppx),             /*  not yet, probably in future, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ */
       (min-resolution: 192dpi)             /*  works for non css3 browser */
       {
            /* your styles go here */
       }
```

- the Opera values should be 1/1, 3/2, 2/1 equivalent to 1, 1.5 and 2.
- dpi values should be 96, 144, 192 equivalent to 1, 1.5 and 2.

when using -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-sizes won't explode on iPhone when turning from portrait to landscape mode ;-)